# Dúvida sobre contabilizar '\n' em C

Tags: c

Tenho que contabilizar a quantidade de caracteres e de quebras de linha no meu arquivo.Fiz da seguinte maneira:

A ideia é contabilizar a quebra de linha cada vez que alguém der enter, mas eu só posso usar a `getc`.

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int cont = 0;
    int contlinha = 0;
    while (getc(stdin) != EOF) {
        cont++;
        if (getc(stdin) == '\n') {
            contlinha++;
        }
    }
    printf("Caracteres: %d new lines: %d\n", cont, contlinha);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Entretanto esse código me retorna números errados, e ainda por cima o ^Z não sai direto quando abro no `cmd`. O que há de errado ? Não consigo enxergar o que não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está lendo duas vezes. Use o getc apenas no while e guarde o resultado em uma variável. Dentro do loop teste esta variável.

```
include < stdio.h >
include< stdlib.h >

int main(void) {
    int cont = 0;
    int contlinha = 0;
     int c;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        cont++;
        if (c == '\n') {
            contlinha++;
        }
    }
    printf("Caracteres: %d new lines: %d\n", cont, contlinha);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário